# Does Bi'Kdei Sh'Yaasu apply beyond Shabbat?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I know that certain things are forbidden on the Sabbath and if a non-Jew does them, a Jew can only benefit from them if he waits a certain length of time. This has been covered in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15230/melachah-on-shabbath-after-shabbath) question and [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14726/are-you-allowed-to-benefit-from-an-electrical-appliance-turned-on-during-shabbos) one. So if a non-Jew (unbeknownst to me) calls a cab to arrive for me at the end of the Sabbath, I have to wait to get in for the amount of time that it would have taken me to call, and him to arrive. And if the non-Jew turns a light on for me intentionally on the Sabbath, I have to keep my eyes closed.

But does the same logic hold in areas beyond the Sabbath? For example -- one is forbidden to think Torah thoughts in the [bathroom](http://dinonline.org/2015/09/30/torah-in-the-bathroom/). But what if my mind wanders while I am in there, and I think of a great chiddush! Do I have to wait after I exit for the amount of time it would have taken me to think of it outside the bathroom before I can tell anyone?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).