# Israel News internet postings originated on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, time-zone

On Friday afternoon in the U.S., am I permitted to click on a news site from Israel which I presume is maintained by Jews in Israel and continually updated by them, even on Shabbat (e.g., Jerusalem Post).  Since it is already Shabbos for the Israel-based employees who are updating their website, am I inappropriately receiving benefit from a Jew’s work performed on Shabbos and thereby prohibited by “Maaseh Shabbos", benefitting from work that was done by a Jew on Shabbos if I read the articles which are newly posted after it is Shabbos in Israel?  If this prohibition were to apply, then I can never look at those postings which originated on Shabbos.

Comment: relevant: [Melachah on Shabbath](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15246/11501)

Answer (score 1):

It is forbidden to benefit from a melachah performed intentionally by a Jew on Shabbos itself - but immediately on Motze Shabbos, it is permitted (Sh"A Orach Chaim §318).

It would therefore be permitted to benefit from the melachah performed by the site *after* Shabbos.

[The Pri Megadim [A.A §325.22] posits that when the Melacha is performed by a *yisroel mumar*, it becomes forbidden forever. According to this, it is possible that in our case it would be forbidden even after Shabbos. See, however, Minchas Yitzchok Chelek 3, §78.]

What remains to be clarified is whether on Friday - before Motze Shabbos, but not technically *bo bayom*, it is permitted or not. Is the prohibition specifically on Shabbos, or is it simply assur until Motze Shabbos? [I would venture to say it is prohibited, but have no source offhand.]

Comment: Hi...they were asking if it's permitted to read the news posted in galut before shabbat, while the news was posted *on* shabbat in Israel. So it seems it would be forbidden until *after* shabbat. See edit.

Comment: A Jew did a melacha for a Jew it is also forbidden for that Jew forever