# Can you benefit from items bought on shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, transactions, sin

Say someone purchased clothing on shabbat--knowing that it was a violation--can that clothing be worn?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14726/are-you-allowed-to-benefit-from-an-electrical-appliance-turned-on-during-shabbos

Answer (score 2):

Since you say the purchaser knows his act was "a violation", I'll assume he's Jewish. For the same reason, I won't discuss here a case in which someone did a prohibited act *without* knowing that what he was doing was wrong. (The rules are somewhat different in such a case.) Thus, **caveat lector**: the below is about cases in which the *Shabas*-violator knew he was violating *Shabas*.

---

If something is cooked by a Jew on *Shabas* the cooked food cannot be eaten on that *Shabas*, and is forbidden *to him* forever. (*Shulchan Aruch* 318:1.) The commentators note that the same is true for other prohibitions, not just cooking.

But *Beur Halacha* ("אחת משאר מלאכות", quoting *Chaye Adam*) says that if a forbidden act done on an object did not physically change the object in any way (e.g. something was [carried](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot)), then it's prohibited only until the close of *Shabas*, even for the violator. He (still quoting *Chaye Adam*) adds that if the forbidden act, though it didn't physically change the object, was a divine prohibition then one should not allow himself that lessening of the restrictions, but should consider the object prohibited as per the general rule above.

But buying clothes on *Shabas* is **usually** not a divine prohibition. (It can be in some circumstances.) So in most cases, you would not be allowed to use the garment on *Shabas*, but it would be permitted afterward. Even if a divine prohibition were violated, the garment would be permitted to everyone but the violator.

---

This is a general discussion based on *Shulchan Aruch* and others. If the question is relevant to you, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).