# Viewing Pictures taken on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat

Is it considered Maase Shabbat (benefiting from someone who violated the Shabbat) if one looks online on a social media page at digital pictures taken on Shabbat?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14726/are-you-allowed-to-benefit-from-an-electrical-appliance-turned-on-during-shabbos

Comment: Are you asking about Maase Shabbat in general or whether digital photography on Shabbos is Deorayto or Derabanan?

Comment: See Shulchan Aruch 318:1.